# What can I infer from similar accuracy using two different DNN architectures?

Tags: deep-learning

I am working on a 'two-class classification of multivariate time-series' problem. I used two different approaches:

1) Manual time-series feature engineering (such as slope, intercept, variance, etc. using tsfresh python library) followed by a multi-layer perceptron.

2) Conv1D followed by LSTM followed by Dense layers (keras/Python) without any feature engineering.

They both yield very similar results (~40% precision, ~95% recall).

Can I infer anything from the similarity of results from two different architectures?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to make a science-backed inference, would be if you fine-tuned both of your proposed solutions, to ensure that both are performing at their maximum potential. Only then you can say that method A is better than method B, otherwise it might just be a matter of improper selection of parameters that leads to those results.

However, if both methods still yield similar results after you have fine-tuned them, then you can follow [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) and select the simplest one as the best one. By simplest, you can consider the one with the least amount of parameters and least time needed for training/inference.